# How can I write 'Mr. Firstname Lastname' first, and then 'Mr. Lastname' thereafter automatically?

Tags: luatex

First-of I'm **NOT** referring to bibtex or something similar.

My goal is to write:

```
 I spoke to \somecommand{Mustermann} and confirmed the data.
After that, \somecommand{Mustermann} told me this and that. \\
% or simpler:
first occurrence: \somecommand{Mustermann} \\
every other occurrence: \somecommand{Mustermann}
```

Which should result in (Something like abbreviations):

```
I spoke to Mr. Max Mustermann and confirmed the data. After that, Mr. Mustermann told me this and that.  
first occurrence: Mr. Max Mustermann
every other occurrence: Mr. Mustermann
```

This would dynamically add the first-name at the first occurrence.
I could solve this with abbreviations, but I don't want them showing up in my abbreviation list.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could have a look into one of the packages for acronyms. They usually have some mechanism to print the long form for the first usage and a short version thereafter.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do have such package, but I don't want it to appear in the acronym listing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a macro which redefines itself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mustermann}{\renewcommand*{\mustermann}{Mr.~Mustermann}Mr.~Max Mustermann}

\begin{document}

first occurrence: \mustermann\par
every other occurrence: \mustermann

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can define "names" in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\newname}[3]{% #1: prefix/title; #2: given name; #3: family name
   \expandafter\newcommand\csname name@\detokenize{#3}\endcsname{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname name@\detokenize{#3}\endcsname{#1~#3}#1~#2 #3}
}
\newcommand{\usename}[1]{%
   \ifcsname name@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
      \csname name@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
   \else
      ???%
   \fi
   }

\newname{Mr.}{Max}{Mustermann}
\newname{Ms.}{Erika}{Musterfrau}

\begin{document}

See \usename{Mustermann}, and then \usename{Mustermann}
as well as \usename{Musterfrau}, \usename{Mustermann},
\usename{Musterfrau}, and \usename{Musterkind}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case of homonymy, a slightly different approach would be to define "labels"

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\newname}[3]{% #1=label; #2=first occurrence; #3=further occurrences
   \expandafter\newcommand\csname name@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname name@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname{#3}#2}
}
\newcommand{\usename}[1]{%
   \ifcsname name@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
      \csname name@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
   \else
      ???%
   \fi
}
\newname{foo}{Mr.~Max Mustermann}{Mr.~Mustermann}
\newname{baz}{Ms.~Erika Musterfrau}{Ms.~Musterfrau}

\begin{document}

See \usename{foo}, and then \usename{foo}
as well as \usename{baz}, \usename{foo},
\usename{baz}, and \usename{bar}.

\end{document}
```

(Same output as above.)

Comment: T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶k̶s̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶i̶n̶g̶,̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶I̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶"̶M̶u̶s̶t̶e̶r̶m̶a̶n̶n̶"̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶c̶o̶n̶d̶ ̶o̶c̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶c̶e̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶m̶e̶n̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶m̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶x̶t̶r̶a̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ This works! Thank you very much! (at first I wrote `\inout` instead of `\input`